# Spark Streaming Real time integration with Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have integrated Spark Streaming Process with Kafka to read a particular topic. Created Spark Context with polling time of 5 seconds., it works fine. But in case of if I want to access feeds in real time can I further reduce it to 1 second (will it over kill ?) or is there any other better option to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Spark Structured streaming offers several modes or "Triggers" for processing time.  You can sacrifice throughput for less latency by using the continuous processing mode.  You sacrifice latency for more throughput by increasing the Trigger duration.  You should be fine setting the micro-batch duration to 1s on Scala and 2s on Python.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers